# spring postgresql jpa jta Transaction interleaving not supporting

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, atomikos, pgbouncer

I used spring jpa(hibernate) atomikos jta transaction.Connection closes in 1 minute after first statement execute on the database side(automatically pgbouncer).But Spring transaction continues.
First query execute then call ws or another work do (1 minutes passes).Then second query execute
then throw exception Transaction interleaving not supported.

İf I use non Xa datasource then exception is change statestaleobjectException ,row was updated another transaction or updated(0)..

Comment: I disabled opensessioninview

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation in the PostgreSQL driver. It happens in certain cases, like when you do repeated SQL calls in the same transaction.

I am not sure if you have a budget, but the Atomikos free trial of ExtremeTransactions (the commercial version of the product) includes a workaround for this.

If interested then you can apply here: http://atomikos.com/Main/ExtremeTransactionsFreeTrial

Cheers

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately expensive for us